# Running Powershell script with if condition from a .NET app

Tags: vb.net, powershell, file-io, if-statement

I have a .net application that successfully runs Powershell commands that it pulls from text files- until I tried doing one that is more complicated and contains an if condition. The script works correctly from a PS console but in .NET I only know how to pass in a string for the script, which after reading the file, it adds extra stuff like vblf and even if I take it out, it won't work. Is this even possible?

> .NET Runtime Error: Server was unable to process request. ---> The
>   term 'False' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
>   script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
>   if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

**.NET code:**

```vb
'Grab Powershell script from text (.ps1) file
strScript = File.ReadAllText(ScriptFileName)

'inject the arguments into the script
strScript = InsertArguments(strScript, Arguments)

'Open the runspace and create a pipeline if it's not already open
If psRunspace.RunspaceStateInfo.State = RunspaceState.BeforeOpen Then
  psRunspace.Open()
End If

Dim MyPipeline As Pipeline = psRunspace.CreatePipeline()
MyPipeline.Commands.AddScript(strScript)
Dim psResults As Collection(Of PSObject) = MyPipeline.Invoke()
```

**Powershell Script**, stored in ps1 file:

```
new-mailbox -name $argument1 -DisplayName $argument1 -UserPrincipalName $argument2 Room -DomainController $argument5
if ($argument4 -eq "False") {
   Set-CalendarProcessing $argument1 -BookingWindowInDays 400 -DeleteSubject $false -AutomateProcessing autoaccept -AllBookInPolicy $false -BookInPolicy $argument3 -DomainController $argument5        
} else {
   Set-CalendarProcessing $argument1 -BookingWindowInDays 400 -DeleteSubject $false -AutomateProcessing autoaccept -AllBookInPolicy $true -DomainController $argument5
}
```

When this script is read in, here is a substring of what gets pulled into `strScript`:

```
-Room -DomainController mcexdct1" & vbLf & "if (False -eq "False") {"
```

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting while you are trying this?

Comment: I updated the original post with the error and then when I looked at what was in strScript, I realized that my if condition is the real problem. I temporarily changed it to say if (5 -eq 5) and then everything worked- no error and the new mailbox was created in full. So I just need to figure out how to rewrite that syntax

Comment: I suspect the problem is in `InsertArguments`, which cuts part of the script as a result of its work, in some cases.

Answer (score 3):

Fixed it by changing the PowerShell script from this:

```
if ($argument4 -eq "False") {
```

to this:

```
if ("$argument4" -eq "False") {
```

It works with quotation marks around it. I guess the "junk" I was seeing in the script string (like vblf) is normal- I don't work with reading from text files that much.